# CloudDocs > session folder filled with version of a Pages file

Tags: icloud, finder, pages, system-information

I'm on a 2016 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.13.5

In (User)`Library/Application Support/CloudDocs` there is a folder called `session` weighing approx. 35GB.
Inside there is another folder called `r`(why r?) which contains a few thousand files, 99% of which are what seem to be incremental versions of the same Pages document.

Why are those files there? 
Can I safely delete them? (for your knowledge, I have already copied the original final version of the file elsewhere for backup, just in case).

What is the use of this folder (apart from being the iCloud Drive mirror on the computer's drive)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I have the same folder which is also huge. I'm pretty sure they are indeed incremental files.
I have a few different ones, but there's not one for every Pages file I own, which makes me believe they are the files I wanted to "revert". There's an option in Pages, Preview, Keynote, Numbers and more Apple applications that lets you revert to a previous version. I think what happened is that it saved all previous versions.

I just opened some of those files and tried to revert them, but they don't even revert back to all of those saves! Those gigabytes of files are there but I can't open them and I can't revert to them.
I deleted all of the versions of one document and opened the actual one, the document was still complete.
I did the same with another and the actual document is fine. I think you might be able to delete all of it. Maybe make a backup before you do so if it's an important file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would happen if you delete them, but it doesn't look like it would free up a lot of space. If you select the folder in Finder and get info (cmd I, or File → Get Info), you'll see that it doesn't actually take up that space. In my case, the folder size is 4.15 GB, but it's only 30.7 MB on disk.

That is because on disk, only the differences between the files are saved. I know that the file system APFS has a feature to only store differences between files; but it could also be a macOS feature, just like Time Machine saves only differences between versions of files.

Answer (score 0):

Same here now with OSX version `13.5 beta (22G5038d)` so, the problem is well known by apple.  I think now, as Terminal doesn't show them as normal files but special links to the true iCloud versions… they are not taking room from your hard disk, but on the iCloud versioning system.  I hope so